Утечка памяти при множественных соединениях в net/http Golang
У меня есть следующая функция:
var client = &http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Millisecond * 100,
}

func scan(ip string) (error, string, string, string) {
    resp, err := client.Get("http://" + ip)

    // Закрытие неиспользуемых соединений
    client.CloseIdleConnections()

    if err != nil {
        return err, "", "", ""
    }

    headers := buildHeaders(resp.Header)
    body, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    // закрытие тела ответа
    resp.Body.Close()

    return err, headers, string(body), resp.Status
}

Данный код приводит к огромной утечке памяти. В процессе дебага выяснилось что в net/http в функции queueForIdleConn() в файле transport.go происходит следующее:
if t.idleConnWait == nil {
    t.idleConnWait = make(map[connectMethodKey]wantConnQueue)
}
q := t.idleConnWait[w.key]
q.cleanFront()
q.pushBack(w)
t.idleConnWait[w.key] = q
return false

Получается так что в idleConnWait = {map[http.connectMethodKey]http.wantConnQueue} постоянно записываются новые элементы, но судя по размеру никогда не освобождается. Как правильно сделать так что бы этот массив очищался?
Примечания:

Программа кидает соединения множеству адресов 95% которых недействительны (не отвечают).
Эта функция запускается сразу в большом кол-ве горутин (go scan())


Неактивные подключения удаляются в методе removeIdleConn. рано или поздно TCP соединение завершится по таймауту, и HTTP подключение будет удалено.

проблема в том что функция CloseIdleConnections() (обёртка из клиента для доступа к функции removeIdleConn в транспорте) очищает массив idleConn, но он у меня пустой т.к не было успешных соединений. А вот вся шелуха копится в idleConnWait и которое я не нашёл как очищать


Ну идиоматично использовать для закрытия defer resp.Body.Close(), т.к. в неких пограничных случая, если даже вам вернулась ошибка, тело запроса может быть открыто.

Объявите свой собственный транспорт, там вы сможете ограничить размерность оной маппы:
 var client = &http.Client{
     Timeout: time.Millisecond * 100,
     Transport: &http.Transport{
         MaxIdleConns:        100,
         MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 10,
     },
 }


Если в вашем случае повторное использование соединений не критично, вы можете полностью отключить его, установив параметр DisableKeepAlives в true.
var client = &http.Client{
   Timeout: time.Millisecond * 100,
   Transport: &http.Transport{
       DisableKeepAlives: true,
   },
}



